Account is frozen, custom program error: 0x11
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, VersionedTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { Wallet } from '@project-serum/anchor'
import bs58 from 'bs58'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import axios from 'axios'

dotenv.config()

async function main() {
    try {
        const SOLANA_CLUSTER = clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta');
        const connection = new Connection(SOLANA_CLUSTER, 'confirmed');

        const wallet = new Wallet(Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || '')))

        const quoteResponse = await axios.get('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote', {
            params: {
                inputMint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
                outputMint: '21rweMLGYeMNonHW7H3xa5py17X6ZFRcHirCp9inRBQA',
                amount: 100000000,
                slippageBps: 50,
                swapMode: 'ExactOut',
                onlyDirectRoutes: true,
                asLegacyTransaction: false,
            },
        })

        console.dir(quoteResponse.data, { depth: null })
        const swapResponse = await axios.post('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', {
            quoteResponse: quoteResponse.data,
            userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toString(),
            wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
            prioritizationFeeLamports: 'auto',
        })

        console.log('Swap Response:', swapResponse.data)

        // Deserialize the transaction
        const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapResponse.data.swapTransaction, 'base64')
        const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf)

        // Sign the transaction
        transaction.sign([wallet.payer])

        // We first simulate whether the transaction would be successful
        const { value: simulatedTransactionResponse } = await connection.simulateTransaction(transaction, {
            replaceRecentBlockhash: true,
            commitment: 'processed',
        })
        const { err, logs } = simulatedTransactionResponse

        if (err) {
            // Simulation error, we can check the logs for more details
            // If you are getting an invalid account error, make sure that you have the input mint account to actually swap from.
            console.error('Simulation Error:')
            console.error({ err, logs })
            return
        }

        // Execute the transaction
        const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize()
        const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
            skipPreflight: true,
        })

        console.log(`Transaction initiated. Txid: ${txid}`)
        try {
            await connection.confirmTransaction(txid)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Confirmation error:', error)
        }
        console.log(`View transaction on Solscan: https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error)
    }
}

main()

When I perform a transaction when the outputMint is 21rweMLGYeMNonHW7H3xa5py17X6ZFRcHirCp9inRBQA, it will prompt Program log: Error: Account is frozen, custom program error: 0x11. But I can conduct transactions on the front-end page of Jupiter Aggregator. Other coins do not have this situation and can be successfully traded.

It looks like one of the token accounts involved is frozen, and so cannot be part of any transactions until it is thawed.
